# SharpZipLib - what is the status on this product?

Tags: zip, unzip, sharpziplib

I went to [download SharpZipLib assemblies](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/Download.aspx) but it looks like its not on SourceForge. Is this a problem with their site or is this project no longer available? Is anyone still working on this project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have experienced a temporarily issue with SourceForge.  The downloads are working for me.  It looks like the latest build was on 8/11/2008, so it seems there's still some recent work being done on it.

It's a pretty good library overall.  I've used it in the past and it does the job well.

Good luck!